# Protecting MySQL connection string

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm setting a mysql connection from C# application, but I'm just wondering if this code offers some kind of security against connection string hacks?, I just don't want to expose the connection credentials too much for them to be vulnerable.

```
protected MySqlConnection connection;
protected string server;
protected string database;
protected string uid;
protected string password;


//Initialize values
private void Initialize()
{
    server = "localhost";
    database = "databaseName";
    uid = "username";
    password = "password";
    var connectionString = string.Empty;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
}


//open connection to database
private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        //When handling errors, you can your application's response based on the error number.
        //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
        //0: Cannot connect to server.
        //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                break;

            case 1045:
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a vulnerability. But apart from that, since you're using connection-pooling by default you should always `Open` and `Close` connections as soon as poosible. I would use the `using`-statement. Your `OpenConnection` method suggests that you want to keep it open, i would strongly advise against to prevent locks or other kind of issues (too many open connections etc).

Comment: Why not keep your connection string in your `app.config`/`web.config` and encrypt it?

Comment: Thanks for the info, @TimSchmelter, and I didn't include all the code, but in fact I'm planning in opening and closing connections as needed.

Comment: @DavidG Doesn't that expose the crendetials even more?, I mean, itsn't easier to hack that way?, I suppose it depends on the encryption method and level right?

Comment: @AJ152 Well it's more secure than doing what you are in the code above. It wouldn't be too difficult for someone to take your application and search inside it for the username/password. For example, you can use this application: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439

Comment: Thanks @DavidG I'll consider that